# Posting twitter thread using Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to figure out how to use Twitter4J to post a tweet thread using Twitter4J. I'm guessing it would be somehow using the `StatusUpdate` class, but the documentation is a bit sparse. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set inReplyToStatusId as latest posted status id for every tweet coming after first tweet. Default value for inReplyToStatusId is -1.

Example:

```
long inReplyToStatusId = -1
int counter = 0
int threadLimit = 5

while (counter < threadLimit){
    StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(Integer.toString(counter));
    statusUpdate.setInReplyToStatusId(inReplyToStatusId);

    Status updatedStatus = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);
    inReplyToStatusId = updatedStatus.getId();
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick typo correction: `lastPostedStatusId` should be `inReplyToStatusId`