# how to post a tweet in parts if the Length of my tweet is More Than Twitter Tweet Limit?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

Here is My code for tweeting From my Android app and work fine, if the tweet length is not more than 280 characters, I want to post tweet in multiple parts of 280 characters if the character's length of tweet is more than 280 characters

```
     String PostBody,Tags,Link
     String tweet = PostBody+Tags+Link;

TweetIt(tweet);

}
 public void TweetIt(final String tweet) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    String token = "myToken";
                    String secret = "mySecret";
                    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(token, secret);
                    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("authOne", "authTwo");
                    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
                    try {
                        twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

    }
```

Comment: _"how to post a tweet in parts"_ You'll use methods from the `String` class such as `subString()`, `charAt()` and `length()` to write a logic that splits the text to parts that are at maximum 280 characters long. A raw split is easy and a more elegant (don't split inside a word, add ellipsis "..." to split points etc.) will take a bit more effort, but "coders gotta code".

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply sir,

Comment: can you elaborate as per Above Code? Please. i am a little New in android Development.

Comment: you can post a twitter thread like the example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54168866/2183174

Answer (score 0):

what about spliting the tweet to a number of characters of 280?

```
    int index = 0;
    while (index < tweet.length()) {
       twitter.updateStatus( tweet.substring(index, Math.min(index + 280,tweet.length())));  
       index += 280;
    }
```